# PHP Find data in same row as string in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server, I've got a column called registration. In an HTML page, the user types in a registration. Then, when submit is pressed, I need to run my PHP script and get information in the same row as the registration entered. So, put simply, how do I search the column for a value, and then pull information from the row it is found in? I've got

```
<?php
$db = mssql_connect("10.1.173.21", "jsonrequsr", "");
mssql_select_db("rygorWestburySite",$db);
$result = mssql_query("SELECT Registration, StageOne, StageTwo, StageThree",$db);
$num = mssql_num_rows($result);
$myrow = /* what goes here */;
$i = 1;
if (/* what to put here */) do {
if ($myrow["StageOne"] == "Completed" and $myrow["StageTwo"] == "Incompleted" and $myrow["StageThree"] == "Incompleted") {
    echo "\"itemId\":\"itemid\", \"itemType\":\"JC_AlertView\", \"loadScreenWithItemId\":\"itemid\"";
} elseif ($myrow["StageOne"] == "Completed" and $myrow["StageTwo"] == "Completed" and $myrow["StageThree"] == "Incompleted") {
    echo "\"itemId\":\"itemid\", \"itemType\":\"JC_AlertView\", \"loadScreenWithItemId\":\"itemid\"";
} elseif ($myrow["StageOne"] == "Completed" and $myrow["StageTwo"] == "Completed" and $myrow["StageThree"] == "Completed") {
    echo "\"itemId\":\"itemid\", \"itemType\":\"JC_AlertView\", \"loadScreenWithItemId\":\"itemid\"";
} if ($num > $i) printf(",");
$i++;
} while ($myrow = mssql_fetch_array($result));
else {
echo "Sorry, nothing there to see!";
}
?>
```

so far, and it returns blank... and according to PHP Code Checker, the syntax is all correct so far.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Okay, I misunderstood your problem. What you could do is with an SQL-query find the row using the registration column. That is, the registration columns value has to be unique, for you only to get one item.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where registration = 'user_input';
```

**Pre-edit:**

If you're using AUTO_INCREMENT on your ID column for the registration which you should have, then you can just use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last ID that was inserted and then fetch that row by that ID and show the data that way.

Also you should have an ID (integer) for your table which is the primary key and set to auto increment.

Comment: I don't think that method is going to work if he uses the mssql-library

Comment: I need it so it fetches from a column called registration, not the ID. And also it won't be in order, it will entered by an end-user and the record could be ID 3 or ID 2554

Comment: Edited my answer. Also if you don't know exactly what the users input was checkout the [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator in SQL.

Comment: @Michael That's halfway there! Now I need to store the line that was found on as a variable so I can run 

    if ($myrow["StageOne"] = Complete {
        echo "StageOne"
    }

Comment: Use $var = mssql_result($query, 0, 'StageOne') if you know there's only gonna be one row returned, otherwise use a for-loop and replace 0 with i, [see here for examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-result.php).

Comment: There will be only 1 returned, so that will be good. Thanks. Now, when I run the if command, I need to use if ($var['StageOne']) now?

Comment: No, just $var, since you're just fetching that column, and not the entire row. To fetch a full row use [mssql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: So I should have '$query = mssql_query('SELECT [Registration], [Stage One], [Stage Two], [Stage Three] FROM [GlobalDatabase] WHERE [Registration] = $variable;'?